# Can i use ngxErrors or something like it to display a form error?

Tags: forms, angular, reactive

I use ngxErrors to display errors for a form control and it works great. Is there any way to get similar functionality for a form or a form group? Currently, I display a form error like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="form.hasError('loginFailed')">
  Login Failed
</div>
```

The bummer is, when I detect that there is a form error (e.g. after the login form is submitted) as opposed to control error, I set it like this:

```js
this.form.setErrors({ loginFailed: true });
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Where this.cdr is an instance of ChangeDetectorRef. This is necessary because I'm using OnPush change detection strategy. So basically it's like calling $scope.$apply() from AngularJS all over again.

What I would really like to do is something more like how ngxErrors does it:

```html
<div ngxErrors="myForm">
  <div ngxError="loginFailed" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
  The login has failed
 </div>
```

But ngxErrors expects myForm to be a control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not currently baked into ngxErrors, but I submitted a PR. https://github.com/UltimateAngular/ngxerrors/pull/18

The working syntax is a slight modification of the above:

```js
<div ngxErrors>
  <div ngxError="loginFailed" [when]="['dirty', 'touched']">
    The login has failed
  </div>
</div>
```

I learned that you do not have to tell child components the form, the FormGroupDirective is available to children automatically.

Answer (score 0):

See this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-error-messages for show error messages based on validation rules:

```
<input placeholder="Texto:"  formControlName="text">
<div errorMessage="text" alias="Super Texto" ></div>
```